# How do I correct my code to create a new variable using two specifications in Stata?

Tags: stata, dummy-variable

Please correct my code so that the new variable takes on value 1 if column `treatment ==1` and column `category_assetprovision =="Accepted"` and it takes on the value 0 if column `treatment ==0` & column `category_assetprovision =="Refused"` in Stata.

```
gen treatmentBreakdown = 1 if treatment ==1 & category_assetprovision =="Accepted" and 0 if treatment ==0 & category_assetprovision =="Refused"
```

Please correct my code so that the new variable takes on value 1 if column `treatment ==1` and column `category_assetprovision =="Accepted"` and it takes on the value 0 if column `treatment ==0` & column `category_assetprovision =="Refused"` in Stata.

```
gen treatmentBreakdown = 1 if treatment ==1 & category_assetprovision =="Accepted" and 0 if treatment ==0 & category_assetprovision =="Refused"
```

Comment: In Stata what you call columns are called _variables_.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing what the code might be or what you would like it to be is a poor way to learn the syntax of any language.

What is best here depends on what other possibilities exist. Cautious code for the first might be

```
gen treatmentBreakdown = . 
replace treatmentBreakdown = 1 if treatment ==1 & category_assetprovision =="Accepted" 
replace treatmentBreakdown = 0 if treatment ==0 & category_assetprovision =="Refused"
```

and then the second problem is similar and has a similar solution.

Note that

```
treatment == 0 & category_assetprovision =="Accepted" 

treatment == 1 & category_assetprovision =="Refused"
```

would both be mapped to missing (.) by this code, as would any other two values of those two variables not yet mentioned.

Stata does not support `and` as an operator and it allows only one `if` qualifier in any statement that allows `if` at all.